# Include Grails generated Java class into the grails project

Tags: java, grails, groovy

How can I Include Grails generated java class into the grails project?

How can I use the generated class by grails into a java class in the project.
Use my Groovy class into a Java class of the Grails project. Accesing his methods, attributes, etc...

Example:

I have a Domain class like this:

```
package es.prueba.domain
class Author implements Serializable {
  String firstName
  String lastName

  static hasMany = [books: Book]       

  def relatesToMany = [ books : Book ]

  SortedSet books

  static constraints = {
      books(nullable: true)
  }

}
```

I want to use it in a Java File. In my case I'm using GWT to send objects with the service `AuthorService.groovy`.

I generated the interfaces with rule: `grails generate-gwt-rpc`

BookService:

```
package org.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;

public interface BookService extends RemoteService {
    es.prueba.domain.Author getAuthor(int arg0);
}
```

BookServiceAsync:

```
package org.example.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface BookServiceAsync {
    void getAuthor(int arg0, AsyncCallback callback);
}
```

But I get the exception:

```
No source code is available for type es.prueba.domain.Author; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

When I run the app with: `grails run-app` command.

How can I include source in the project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your domain class in es.prueba.domain package? I don't see a package declaration in your source code example.

cheers

Lee

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace with that exception? Is it being thrown by the plugin code or from the core Grails compile step?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the GWT plugin for Grails but it looks more like a standard GWT issue.

From the GWT documentation about [how to organize projects](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules):

> The default source path is the *client* subpackage underneath where the Module XML File is stored.

You package name is *es.prueba.domain* so GWT does not find it when it looks for source. You have to specify it in your module file (let's say Application.gwt.xml) as specified below:

```
<module>
   <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
   <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>

   <!-- add es.prueba.domain as source path -->
   <source path="domain"/>

   <!-- Specify the module entry point class. -->
   <entry-point class="es.prueba.Application"/>
</module>
```

Comment: `Module: org.example.MyApp.[java] Compiling module org.example.MyApp[java]Computing all possible rebind results for 'org.example.client.MyApp'[java]Rebinding org.example.client.MyApp
[java]Checking rule <generate-with class='com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.rebind.LogMessageFormatterGenerator'
[java][ERROR] Unable to find type 'org.example.client.MyApp'
[java][ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[java][ERROR] Hint:Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly`

Comment: I get this error including the package to load a module in the GWT application.

Thanks but I haven't found anyhting to use the generated classes in a GWT module entry point.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: If I add this path: `<source path="domain"/>` the application couldn't find the GWT module.

Regards.

Comment: I suspect that org.example.client.MyApp is the path of your module (MyApp.gwt.xml). If you add <source path="domain"/>, GWT is going to look in org.example.client.domain. Because this path does not exist, you get the error. You've got to move your domain package from es.prueba.domain to org.example.client.domain.